# Microsoft GRAPH API possible without Azure App Registration?

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, azureportal

I would like to try out Microsoft GRAPH API. But as far as I can tell there is no way to test it without App Registration client and tenant id in the Azure Portal. Is this correct? I don't have access to App Registration on Azure so if this is correct then I need to contact admin, which means I need to start a whole long-winded process.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, this is not possible, to access the graph api, (for a work or student account) there must be an app registration to give you permissions to those endpoints.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is misleading. This is possible using the [Microsoft Graph PowerShell SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/microsoftgraph/get-started?view=graph-powershell-1.0).

Comment: Would it be possible to create an access token using this SDK so that I could use it with a different client, e.g. Postman?
And is it possible to use the Azure CLI as well? If not, is there any documentation about that?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible IFF you are just trying to do CRUD operations and other GET requests that doesn't require an admin consent.

You can check the same inside Graph Explorer, for the requests that require your/admin's consent.

You must also consider that the access token gets refreshed when you try to integrate it with any code.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).